# Automating Export of an image where the only thing that changes is the text layer?

Tags: gimp, automation

Good morning all...

I am wondering if there is a way to automate export of an image that will have a variation for each state, where the only thing that changes on the image is the text layer that includes the name of the state, using a simple text file that lists all of the possible word variations.

I know the sample in the example is small, I'm just trying to find a solution that I can use on lists where the variations are measured in the thousands.

Thanks!

Comment: [one possible solution](http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/44309-excel-to-gimp-pluginscript/) (albeit the thread looks a bit old)

Comment: What software are you using for this?

Comment: I am using GIMP.  I got a script running that does this, but the font sizing solution is a hack.  I have established a character string length default, and any time a word is processed that has more characters than the default string, I reduce the font size by a provided font reduction value.

Answer (score 0):

Gimp is overkill for this. There are plenty of ways to do this in the command line using a script based on [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/).

If you have a file with the list of labels producing the script is a mere matter of passing a few global editor commands to change each line into a command that adds the label to the source image.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.  I am doing this for graphic design, so I am working at a very high resolution.  I need access to the font vectors, which Is why I was trying to get it done in GIMP.

I got a script running that does resolve the problem as I described it, but the font sizing solution is a hack. I have established a character string length default, and any time a word is processed that has more characters than the default string, I reduce the font size by a provided font reduction value.  This obviously doesn't work because some letters are way wider than others...

Comment: See second answer then...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust font size:

#### ImageMagick:

You can use IM's `convert` to produce the label, measure it (see IM's `identify` utility) and if it's too big interpolate a better font size and retry. Once you have the label you use IM's `compose` to put the label over the picture.

#### GIMP:

In a Gimp script you can do the same, using the width of the generated text layer. An alternative is to produce the path/vectors from the text, and scale it to the required size and then select/fill it. But text at size 15 is not 3/4 of the font at size 20, there are subtleties, so iterating the font size will likely give better results.